# How does a 3ds Max store normals in a Mesh class?

Tags: c++, 3d, 3dsmax, normals

I'm writing a 3ds Max exporter and I need to get mesh normals computed by the application. I have a `Mesh` instance and I can get vertex positions, UVs, colors, etc. but the normals seem to be not so easy... BTW: I know how to compute face/vertex normals, but I need the exact data from 3ds Max, with smoothing groups and material index taken into account.

For this case I've created a simple box and looked into resulting `Mesh` instance after calling the `buildNormals()` method. Here is what I've found after some debugging and digging into documentation, all mentioned data are inside of a `Mesh` class:

I have simple vertex/face numbers:

```
int numVerts = 8;
int numFaces = 12;
```

And verices/faces data:

```
Point3* verts;    // contains 8 vectors with positions (x,y,z)
Face*   faces;    // contains 12 faces, each with 3 indexes into *verts - [0-7]
```

So far so good... Now I have computed normals data:

```
int normalCount = 24;  // 6 sides * 4 vertices each, no reuse of normal data
Point3* gfxNormals;    // contains 24 normal vectors
```

At this point I have almost all the data I need but I can't assign one normal to one rendered vertex. There is one more interesting table:

```
Tab<ulong> norInd;    // contains 8 indexes - {0,3,6,9,12,15,18,21}
```

It seems to be somehow connected to previous fields (I have 8 verts, each has 3 normals) but I have no idea how to use it in more complex situations.

### What I need to get:

I need an index of normal for particular vertex in particular face, or in other words - if I wanted to render 0'th face in OpenGl I could use:

```
glVertex3f( verts[ faces[0].v[0] ].x, verts[ faces[0].v[0] ].y, verts[ faces[0].v[0] ].z );
glVertex3f( verts[ faces[0].v[1] ].x, verts[ faces[0].v[1] ].y, verts[ faces[0].v[1] ].z );    
glVertex3f( verts[ faces[0].v[2] ].x, verts[ faces[0].v[2] ].y, verts[ faces[0].v[2] ].z );
```

But what to pass to `glNormal3f()`?

Answer (score 1):

The way I get them is this:

```
for(int f = 0; f < mesh->numFaces; ++f)
{
        Point3 normal;
        Face* face = &mesh->faces[f];

        for(int v = 0; v < 3; ++v)
        {
                DWORD vi = face->v[v];
                Point3 normal;
                if(mesh->getRVertPtr(vi))
                        normal = GetVertexNormal(mesh, f, mesh->getRVertPtr(vi));
                else
                        normal = Point3(0, 0, 1);       
                fprintf(file, "\t\t\t<normal x=\"%f\" y=\"%f\" z=\"%f\" />\n", normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stig. I didn't have time to check your solution yet, but when I have some I'll get back to this topic and accept your solution if it works :).